# Maven antrun plugin maven-resources-plugin executed multiple times

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a project using Maven, and in one module while compiling on Jenkins is calling 3 times the plugin maven-resources-plugin (not only this plugin but also others in the same module). The compilation is working fine on my local, running once one.

Follow the command executed in Jenkins:

```
mvn -e -X clean source:jar package install deploy -Pint
```

Follow my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v10.12.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install --verbose</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>gulp compile --prod</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>gulp</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>compile --prod</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>resources/deployment/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>resources/deployment/web.xml</webXml>
                <warSourceDirectory>app/build/prod</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

My parent pom.xml has some profiles, but only one is activated by default.

INFO: It is important to notice that this issue only occurs on Jenkins, and I cannot reproduce it on my local.

Follow also a code-snipped of my parent pom.xml:

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>core</module>
            <module>service</module>
            <module>mapping</module>
            <module>ui</module>
            <module>breaking-module</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <modules>
            <module>core</module>
            <module>service</module>
            <module>mapping</module>
            <module>breaking-module</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>si</id>
        <modules>
            <module>core</module>
            <module>service</module>
            <module>mapping</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>int</id>
        <modules>
            <module>core</module>
            <module>service</module>
            <module>mapping</module>
            <module>ui</module>
            <module>breaking-module</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Follow the error trace with the failing resources:

```
[pathconvert] Set property core.file.full.path = 
/data/jenkins_workspace/workspace/HotfixFinish/breaking-module/target/war/com.project/ui-root-platform/config-bbstatic-1.0.1-230531075633.js//data/jenkins_workspace/workspace/HotfixFinish/breaking-module/target/war/com.project/ui-root-platform/config-bbstatic-1.0.1-230531075757.js//data/jenkins_workspace/workspace/HotfixFinish/breaking-module/target/war/com.project/ui-root-platform/config-bbstatic-1.0.1-230531075916.js
Setting project property: core.file.full.path -> /data/jenkins_workspace/workspace/HotfixFinish/breaking-module/target/war/com.project/ui-root-platform/config-bbstatic-1.0.1-230531075633.js//data/jenkins_workspace/workspace/HotfixFinish/breaking-module/target/war/com.project/ui-root-platform/config-bbstatic-1.0.1-230531075757.js//data/jenkins_workspace/workspace/HotfixFinish/breaking-module/target/war/com.project/ui-root-platform/config-bbstatic-1.0.1-230531075916.js
```

Comment: Use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Comment: The calling of the given plugin calling 3 times `maven-resources-plugin` is understandable because you are triggering `package install deploy` which means you are starting three times the life cycle which means 3 times resources-plugin etc. You can simplify that into `deploy`...

Comment: BTW: I've seen that you are having profiles with different module set which is a bad idea ... you should never make usage of module dependending on a profile... etc..

Comment: @khmarbaise your suggestion has guided me in the right direction. After changing the actions on Jenkins from mvn package install deploy to mvn deploy it stopped duplicating the executions. The action deploy already contains the package and install on it, so adding it into the command line will force maven to re-execute it.

Comment: To deploy artifacts you only need `mvn deploy` nothing else... that includes the install parts, etc. you should check the life cycle https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle#lifecycle-reference also upgrade all the plugins etc... because you are using very old versions...https://maven.apache.org/plugins/